# How to run a Django project without a manage.py file?

Tags: python, django

I'm not experienced with Django. I just want to get this project running on a localhost (on Mac). Normally I run `python manage.py runserver` inside a `virtualenv` but I can't do that without a `manage.py` file! I must be doing something obviously wrong if this project has 264 GitHub stars.

https://github.com/shacker/django-todo

How can I make this work?

Comment: It is an extension you have to add it to an existing Django instance as described in the README.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's almost impossible to get a project running without manage.py not just because of the server but also the migrations..

Second, the django codes in the github link especially the **todo** folder is an **app** of a django project and you need to add that on your `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py` file

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't tell me how to get a local server running where I can actually create todos and stuff.

Comment: You can read on this link for starters: https://github.com/shacker/django-todo/wiki/Requirements-and-Installation

Comment: Ok so please tell me how step 3 is supposed to work without a manage.py file..? `python manage.py migrate todo`

Comment: There's a 'before installing to-do' section at the top saying that you need to have an existing django project site.. Which means you will just integrate the 'todo' besides it says that you will use 'pip' for installation

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But I gave up at `no such table: django_site`

Comment: comment the 'todo' section in the urls.py then you can do the python manage.py migrate.. after you've migrated add back 'todo' in the urls.py and it should be good

Answer (score -1):

setup script is used to install whole project with required dependency packages, once you done with setup script installation then you can import that project into your local project
 Goto Project directory and run below commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver
```

Finally u can see the project in the browser http://127.0.0.1:8000